# Push in existing local table failure (windows): InvalidRegionNumberException then IllegalArgumentException

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

I want to push data into an already existing table, single column family, no records.
I am using shc-core:1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11 on a windows machine. I have hbase 1.2.6 installed and use scala 2.11.8.

When I try to push data I got first the following error: `org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.InvalidRegionNumberException: Number of regions specified for new table must be greater than 3.`

After following the advice of this link https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc/issues/249#issue-318285217, I added: `HBaseTableCatalog.newTable -> "5"` to my options.
It still failed but with: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from a null string`.

Following this link: https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc/issues/151#issuecomment-313800739, I added to my catalog: `, "tableCoder":"PrimitiveType"`.
Still facing the same error.

I saw people are expecting some clarification about this issue (https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc/issues/249#issuecomment-463528032).

It is known issue and apparently it seems fixed (https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc/issues/155#issuecomment-315236736).
I do not know what to do next.
Is there a solution about this?